# Unable to open Firefox private window from Desktop panel/favourites in Ubuntu 22 / Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, gnome-shell

Running Firefox (latest, I assume) on Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome desktop (GNOME Shell 42.9).

Initially, the Firefox launcher on the favourites on the left of the desktop was working perfectly well.  Now, Right-click on the launcher to then select "Open a New Private Window" is no longer working [[ I'm just noticing now that "Open a New Window" or the item above, "New Window", do not work either ]]. Strangely enough, it was gradual: at first, it would just take a long time to open the private window; then, at some point it would only work if I do the action again while the mouse pointer is showing the "waiting animation" .... At this point in time (for a couple of weeks now), it simply won't work. The mouse pointer shows the "waiting" animation for approx. 8 or 10 seconds, then disappears. Firefox does not open at all (no exceptions, it *always* fails to open).

I removed the launcher and created it again. No change.

I can make it work from a terminal, running `firefox --private-window`. That one works reliably; has not failed a single time so far. It does show several errors, but the private window still opens, no exceptions:

```
$ firefox --private-window 
Gtk-Message: 15:19:41.738: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

(firefox:346933): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:19:42.057: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/3068/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 15:19:42.057: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(firefox:346933): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:19:42.058: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/3068/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 15:19:42.058: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

How can I fix this? (pretty much every other launcher works — Chromium, Thunderbird, terminal, calculator, gimp, kwrite .... they all work without glitches)